# Why this "fragment cache" won't work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

I've just tried to implement caching when it's loading example.com/communities?sort=popular

My code is just like this. However it seems caching is not working.
It looks like it's still sending SQL every time it reloads...

What's wrong?
Then When after the user made or edited "Community" record, I'd like to clear all the stored caches that contains the string "community_index_sort_by_".

**config/environment/development.rb**

```
...
config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.cache_store = :dalli_store
...
```

**community_controller.rb**

```
def index

    @key = "community_index_sort_by_" + params[:sort].to_s + "_page_" + params[:page].to_s

    if params[:sort] == 'popular'
        unless read_fragment(:controller => "communities", :action => "index",  :action_suffix => @key)
            @communities = Community.scoped.page(params[:page]).order("cached_votes_up DESC")
        end
    elsif params[:sort] == 'latest'
        @communities = Community.scoped.page(params[:page]).order("created_at DESC")
    end

end
```

I haven't touched in view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've shown only attempts to read from the cache, it never stores anything to it. If you want to populate the cache if no value is found (e.g., on a cache miss) you can use [`Rails.cache.fetch`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html#method-i-fetch) rather than `read_fragment`. `fetch` will return the cached value if one exists. Otherwise, if a block was passed then it will be run when a cache miss occurs and the return value will be stored in the cache. For instance, the relevant part of your code snippet would be something like

```
@communities = Rails.cache.fetch(["communities", "index", @key]) do
  Community.scoped.page(params[:page]).order("cached_votes_up DESC")
end
```

The recommended approach for expiring cached data when an object is modified is to have the cache key include some piece of data that changes whenever the object is modified. This is commonly an `updated_at` timestamp field, which ActiveRecord will automatically update when the object is saved. The `updated_at` field also has the advantage of being automatically used as part of the cache key when the object is used directly as part of the cache key (e.g., a cache key of `@community` would result in a cache key of something like `communities/1-20130116113736`). This will typically require a small amount of restructuring to ensure that a relevant object is available to be used in the cache key. David Heinemeier Hansson [discusses this in more detail](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3113-how-key-based-cache-expiration-works). Step 5 in particular is most relevant to what I've mentioned here.

Comment: that sounds useful. So how can I write that in controller? if you could show me how to do it with expiring time, that'll be so appriciable:)

Comment: could you please please show me an example with code? to set up the caching to fetch, create and clear all.

Comment: I added an example for the fetch / create side of things. The expiry side is hard to provide more information on without knowing more about your data model.

Comment: Thanks so much for an example:) for expiring, I just want to clear all the cache that contains this string "community_index_sort_by_". just only when Community record is updated or Created. But This Community's column "last_active_at" column will be updated from other controllers, too. Like `Topic`, and `Comment` models.  Association is like this `Community`> (has_many) > `Topic` > (has_many) > `Comments`

Comment: Hmm. It may be that there's not an obvious object to use with key-based cache expiration in your scenario. If that's the case you could explicitly invalidate the cache by calling `Rails.cache.delete` with the same cache key as you're using in your controller. You'd typically make these explicit calls from a "Sweeper" class's `after_create` / `after_update` / `after_destroy` methods. See the [Caching on Rails section on Sweepers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) for information.

Comment: Thanks. I'm so stucked because I use params and pagination. If I don't use them it seems it's easy to implement caching to my application. However, cache won't care about params so that they recognize both of these as the same, and it returns the same result. That's why I made @key like my way.  `example.com/communities?page=2&sort=popular` and `example.com/communities?`

Comment: I also use other params in community#index action like this `example.com/communities?location=1&genre=4&search` However, I don't need cache for this because it will be way too many pattern caches if it'll be created every time when user do the search in this page.